# Как правильно выводить шаблоны?

Tags: php, mysql, twig

Есть таблица с товарами, которая имеет следующую структуру:

```
|ID       |NAME            |COUNT        |PROVIDER          |DATEOFPURCHASE      |CATEGORY          
|1        |Банан           |20           |Иван              |2007-01-01          |Fruits
|2        |Помидор         |500          |                  |2001-01-01          |Vegetables
|1        |Телефон         |2            |Альбинос          |                    |Phone
```

Делаю запрос в бд и вывожу товары с выбранной категорией

```
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $stock_list = [];
    $stock_view = $dbpdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products 
                                   WHERE  category = ? 
                                   AND count > 0 
                                   ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stock_view->execute([$category]);
    if($stock_view->rowCount()>0) {
        while ($row = $stock_view->fetch()) {
        //заполняю массив
        $stock_list[] = [
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'count' =>  $row['count'],
                'provider' => $row['provider'],
                'date' => $row['DATEOFPURCHASE']
            ]; 

       }

      //далее отправляю массив в шаблон
       echo $tpl = $twig->render('page/tpl.twig', ['table' => $stock_list]);
    }
```

Теперь с чем у меня возникает проблема. Для примера я тут привел всего несколько столбцов и категорий, но на деле их больше и в зависимости от категории товара, выводиться таблица, например для Vegetables столбец provider не нужно выводить, а для фруктов нужно и так же для телефонов не нужно DATEOFPURCHASE а для остальных нужно.
Единственный вариант, который пришел мне в голову, это в твиге сделать шаблон для каждой категории и проверять категорию if-ми  и выводить нужный блок. Но мне кажется, что этот вариант ужасный и явно есть решение по лучше. Можно было бы сделать ифами, если было всего 2-3 категории, то не критично сделать пару шаблонов и страниц, но пару месяцев назад было 5 категорий а сейчас 30, не уверен, что через год не будет 200 и писать для каждого свой шаблон думаю не лучший вариант. Каким образом это можно автоматизировать

Пожалуйста, помогите мне решить эту проблему, буду благодарен.
Любая информация по теме будет полезна.

Comment: наверное имелось в виду order by а не group by

Comment: @Ипатьев исправил

Comment: мне кажется что автоматизировать никак нельзя. тут ужасен не вариант вывода а сама задача вывода столь разноплановых данных на одной странице.

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо за ваше мнение, правда меньше всего хотелось бы переписывать все :( буду думать

Comment: кстати, пусть категорий и 30, но типов данных же все равно меньше. фрукты и овощи выводятся одним и тем же шаблоном. Так что не стоит преувеличивать сложность проблемы

Comment: @Ипатьев возможно, да немного утрировано написал, но все же хотелось бы писать код более правильней и не использовать if-ы там где не нужно. Просто я подумал сейчас у меня все пару категорий и типов (на самом деле их больше, я просто для примера привел тут меньше)  и я вполне легко обошёлся ифами, но что бы я делал, если бы их было много. Что если была бы задача сделать так. Каждый раз я захожу в этот файл и добавляю if, когда появляется новая категория

Comment: @Ипатьев  С такими темпами через год-два у меня будет очень много ифов. Есть много crm-ов где такое используется, и вряд ли там ифы используют. Вот я и хотел узнать, что там используется

Comment: ну там очевидно используется свой шаблон под каждый тип

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение - создать для каждой уникальной группы товаров свои таблицы в базе данных. Например в Помидоре и Телефоне ненужно выводить PROVIDER, значит создаёшь таблицу без параметра PROVIDER. В Банане и Яблоке наоборот нужно выводить PROVIDER, но ненужно выводить DATEOFPURCHASE, значит создаешь таблицу без параметра DATEOFPURCHASE. Надеюсь, что внятно объяснил